# How to specify python file in AWS handler if code file inside zip file on s3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, zip

I have created a zip file deployment package that is 38mb that I was advised to put into s3 and call into aws lambda.

For the handler in aws lambda, it says I should the name of my and `lambda_handler`.

I am getting error `Unable to import module 'lambda': No module named 'lambda'`

lambda is my zip file and `aws_lambda_function` is my python file in the zip file.

I get the above error, when I enter `aws_lambda_function` as well into handler.

How do I specify the file name in handler in my zip file?

```
from boto3.session import Session
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import s3fs
import uuid


def lambda_handler(event, context):
             rest of code
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to make sure that the package file you have uploaded to S3 has the following structure:

```
some_function.zip
│ somel_library_here
└ foo.py
```

I.e. the file where your **handler** resides as at top level along with the required libraries.

Now, **handler** is how AWS call the entry function of your Lambda code, BUT you can call it whatever you like as long as you provide it in the field called Handler.

[image]

So in the example, the file is called `foo.py` and the entry function is called `lambda_handler` and resides inside it, but as I said, all these are user defined.

Comment: that worked but got new error that I will ask in seperate question `Syntax error in module 'aws_lambda_function': invalid syntax (uuid.py, line 138)`